# Troubleshooting when starting Ubuntu 18 in a VM using Virtualbox in Windows 10

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gui

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a VM in Windows 10 using Virtualbox 6.0.4. I was working normally without a problem for several days using the Ubuntu Studio interface. The next time I started the VM it started directly in the terminal and lost access to the graphics interface. I restarted the VM many times as well as Windows 10, however the the issue is still there.

Is there any command from the terminal to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you rebooted the VM? Do you see any error messages?  Have you looked in the logs? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Did any updates to Ubuntu? Any non-standard software repositories? Is it a plain Ubuntu 18.04, or a derived distribution, like Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: It is Ubuntu Studio distribution